# Как установить расширение magickwand для PHP через ssh?

Tags: apache, php, ssh, ubuntu

ОС `Ubuntu 12.04`. Вместе с `imagemagick` этот `magickwand` почему то не идёт в комплекте.

Answer (score 1):

Вот [так](http://forum.nic.ru/showthread.php?t=5890), например, а вообще все инструкции на [оригинальном сайте](http://www.magickwand.org/).